# Understanding Android camera SurfaceTexture and MediaCodec Surface usage

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, android-mediacodec, egl

I'm trying to understand graphics memory usage/flow in Android and specifically with respect to encoding frames from the camera using `MediaCodec`. In order to do that I'm having to understand a bunch of graphics, OpenGL, and Android terminology/concepts that are unclear to me. I've read the Android graphics architecture material, a bunch of SO questions, and a bunch of source but I'm still confused primarily because it seems that terms have different meanings in different contexts.

I've looked at CameraToMpegTest from fadden's site [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt). My specific question is how `MediaCodec::createInputSurface()` works in conjunction with `Camera::setPreviewTexture()`. It seems that an OpenGL texture is created and then this is used to create an Android `SurfaceTexture` which can then be passed to `setPreviewTexture()`. My specific questions:

1. What does calling `setPreviewTexture()` actually do in terms of what memory buffer the frames go to from the camera?
2. From my understanding an OpenGL texture is a chunk of memory that is accessible by the GPU. On Android this has to be allocated using gralloc with the correct usage flags. The Android description of `SurfaceTexture` mentions that it allows you to "stream images to a given OpenGL texture": https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html#SurfaceTexture(int). What does a `SurfaceTexture` do on top of an OpenGL texture?
3. `MediaCodec::createInputSurface()` returns an Android `Surface`. As I understand it an Android `Surface` represents the producer side of a buffer queue so it may be multiple buffers. The [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html#createInputSurface()) mentions that "the Surface must be rendered with a hardware-accelerated API, such as OpenGL ES". How do the frames captured by the camera get from the `SurfaceTexture` to this `Surface` that is input to the encoder? I see CameraToMpegTest creates an `EGLSurface` using this `Surface` somehow but not knowing much about EGL I don't get this part.
4. Can someone clarify the usage of "render"? I see things such as "render to a surface", "render to the screen" among other usages that seem to maybe mean different things.

Edit: Follow-up to mstorsjo's responses:

1. I dug into the code for `SurfaceTexture` and `CameraClient::setPreviewTarget()`  in `CameraService` some more to try and understand the inner workings of `Camera::setPreviewTexture()` better and have some more questions. To my original question of understanding the memory allocation it seems like `SurfaceTexture` creates a `BufferQueue` and `CameraService` passes the associated `IGraphicBufferProducer` to the platform camera HAL implementation. The camera HAL can then set the gralloc usage flags appropriately (e.g. `GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_READ_RARELY | GRALLOC_USAGE_SW_WRITE_NEVER | GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_TEXTURE`) and also dequeue buffers from this `BufferQueue`. So the buffers that the camera captures frames into are gralloc allocated buffers with some special usage flags like `GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_TEXTURE`. I work on ARM platforms with unified memory architectures so the GPU and CPU can access the same memory so what kind of impact would the `GRALLOC_USAGE_HW_TEXTURE` flag have on how the buffer is allocated?
2. The OpenGL (ES) part of `SurfaceTexture` seems to mainly be implemented as part of `GLConsumer` and the magic seems to be in `updateTexImage()`. Are there additional buffers being allocated for the OpenGL (ES) texture or is the same gralloc buffer that was filled by the camera able to be used? Is there some memory copying that has to happen here to get the camera pixel data from the gralloc buffer into the OpenGL (ES) texture? I guess I don't understand what calling `updateTexImage()` does.

Answer (score 5):

1. It means that the camera provides the output frames via an opaque handle instead of in a user-provided buffer within the application's address space (if using `setPreviewCallback` or `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer`). This opaque handle, the texture, can be used within OpenGL drawing.
2. Almost. In this case, the OpenGL texture is not a physical chunk of memory, but a handle to a variable chunk of memory within an EGL context. In this case, the sample code itself doesn't actually allocate or size the texture, it only creates a "name"/handle for a texture using `glGenTextures` - it's basically just an integer. Within normal OpenGL (ES), you'd use OpenGL functions to allocate the actual storage for the texture and fill it with content. In this setup, `SurfaceTexture` provides an Android level API/abstraction to populate the texture with data (i.e. allocate storage for it with the right flags, provide it with a size and content) - allowing you to pass the `SurfaceTexture` to other classes that can fill it with data (either `Camera` that takes a `SurfaceTexture` directly, or wrap in the `Surface` class to be able to use it in other contexts). This allows filling the OpenGL texture with content efficiently, without having to pass a buffer of raw data to your application's process and having your app upload it to OpenGL.
3. (Answering points 3 and 4 in reverse order.) OpenGL (ES) is a generic API for drawing. In the normal/original setup, consider a game, you'd have a number of textures for different parts of the game content (backgrounds, props, actors, etc), and then with OpenGL APIs draw this to the screen. The textures could either be more or less just copied as such to the screen, or be wrapped around a 3D object built out of triangles. This is the process called "rendering", taking the input textures and set of triangles and drawing it. In the simplest cases, you would render content straight to the screen. The GPU usually can do the same rendering into any other output buffer as well. In games, it is common to render some scene into a texture, and use that prerendered texture as part of the final render which actually ends up displayed on the screen.
4. An EGL context is created for passing the output from the camera into the encoder input. An EGL context is basically a context for doing OpenGL rendering. The target for the rendering is the Surface from the encoder. That is, whatever graphics is drawn using OpenGL ends up in the encoder input buffer instead of on the screen. Now the scene that is drawn using OpenGL could be any sequence of OpenGL function calls, rendering a game scene into the encoder. (This is what the Android Breakout game recorder example does.) Within the context, an texture handle is created. Instead of filling the texture with content by loading a picure from disk, as in normal game graphics rendering, this is made into a `SurfaceTexture`, to allow `Camera` to fill it with the camera picture. The `SurfaceTexture` class provides a callback, giving a signal when the `Camera` has updated the content. When this callback is received, the EGL context is activated and one frame is rendered into the EGL context output target (which is the encoder input). The rendering itself doesn't do anything fancy, but more or else copies the input texture as-is straight into the output.

This might all sound quite roundabout, but it does give a few benefits:

- The actual raw bits of the camera frames never need to be handled directly within the application code (and potentially never within the application's process and address space at all). For low resolutions, this isn't much of an issue, but the `setPreviewCallback` API is a bottleneck when it comes to higher resolutions.
- You can do color adjustments and anything else you can do within OpenGL, almost for free with GPU acceleration.

Comment: I added some follow-ups to my original question based on your answer.

Comment: I can't comment much on those additional questions - the original question was about what these APIs do from the public Android API point of view (which I know), while the latter questions are about how the platform is implemented, and details only relevant to platform implementers.

Comment: For the last question, I would expect that the SurfaceTexture actually is a set of buffers, more than one, so that the producer (the camera) can write one frame while the consumer (the GL context) can keep on rendering the previous frame. In `updateTexImage()`, I would expect it to swap these buffers. That's only my impression and assumption from the user point of view though, I don't know the actual implementation.